# how to assign a JavaScript variable to an standard salesforce field to prepopulate it on an Standar Page Layout?

Tags: javascript, api, fields, custom, button

I made a custom button that prepopulates fields to create a new task and works fine. But I want to assing a js variable to an standard field (in this case Name or evt2 field of Task) and it does not work, when i check syntax the result is that the js variable does not exist.

My custom button code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}

// Call to log into the API
sforce.connection.session = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";

var requestId = "{!pba__Request__c.pba__ContactId__c}";
var queryString = "Select FirstName, LastName From Contact Where Id='"+requestId+"'";
var result = sforce.connection.query(queryString);
var contact = result.getArray("records");

var firstName = contact[0].FirstName;
var lastName = contact[0].LastName;


window.parent.location.href="{!URLFOR($Action.Event.NewEvent, null, [who_id= pba__Request__c.Id , what_id=pba__Request__c.Id, retURL=URLFOR($Action.pba__Request__c.View, pba__Request__c.Id), evt2=firstName &" "& lastName,evt3=pba__Request__c.Name,evt5="Visita a Centro de Ventas",evt10="Other"])}";
```

Hope someone can give me a hint or a workaroud to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome to salesforce.stackexchange Ivan. We'd actually appriciate it if you post your code in the question itself, you can format it using the {} button in the edit mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing your drinks! Looks like you want client-evaluated code in server-evaluated functions ;-)

Try this:

```
window.parent.location.href="{!URLFOR($Action.Event.NewEvent, null, [
    who_id=pba__Request__c.Id,
    what_id=pba__Request__c.Id,
    retURL=URLFOR($Action.pba__Request__c.View, pba__Request__c.Id),
    evt3=pba__Request__c.Name,
    evt5="Visita a Centro de Ventas",
    evt10="Other"
])}" + '&evt2=' + firstName + ' ' + lastName;
```

Above, see how the **VF** is evaluated first:

```
//gives /00U/e?retURL=___&who_id=___&what_id=___
window.parent.location.href="{!URLFOR($Action.Event.NewEvent, null, [...]}"
```

then the **JS** is evaluated separately and tacked on the end:

```
//gives &evt2=___ ___
'&evt2=' + firstName + ' ' + lastName
```

For bonus points you should use JavaScript `encodeURIComponent()` on firstName and lastName.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, works fine, but there is a little problem, when the field Name or Evt2 is filled out in the new Event page this error is shown: "Error: No matches found". I don´t know if it has to do something with format becauase when i type the same value that is passed the value matches. My previous code look something like `evt2 = pba__Request__c.pba__Contact__c` (the value from the object field directly) but the result was the same, "No matches found", and thought that doing this in a different way (the way I asked help here) would work, but it wouldn't

Comment: I think ya might need to look into your query in Console / Workbench and see why this returns 0 results: `SELECT Id FROM Contact Where Id = pba__Request__c.pba__ContactId__c`

Comment: There is a contact related to that request. The problem is when the Contact field is filled out with what is sent in the URL does not match, but when i copy the content of this pre-populated field and then paste it again on this field it works.

Comment: It´s a little strange, but today It works.